# sketching cubic and quadratic curves

Tags: quadratics, curves

I am confuse about question 'b'.i can do question 'a'.can anybody clarify me please.the questions are:
a)On the same axes sketch the curves given by $y=(x+1)^3$ and $y=3x(x-1)$.

b)Explain how your sketch shows that there is only one solution to the equations $x^3+6x+1=0$.

Generally to find number of solution I would do like this $(x+1)^3=3x(x-1)$ or $(x+1)^3-3x(x+1)=0$ but $x^3+6x+1=0$ is whole new equation.

Comment: If you expand the parentheses, $(x+1)^3 -3x(x-1)=0$ becomes $x^3 + 6x +1 =0$. So they are the same equation in the end.

Comment: (I had a little typo there, it's important to put the plusses and minuses correctly)

Comment: https://goo.gl/mjEoe5

Comment: oh thank you genius friend you are a life saver and money saver.no need to hire a tutor : )

Answer (score 0):

$$(x+1)^3=x^3+3x^2+3x+1$$
$$3x(x-1)=3x^2-3x$$
$$(x+1)^3-3x(x-1)=x^3+6x+1$$
Your graphs should look like this:https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s9xq3jnkbi and you can see that the graphs only have one intersection, so there is only one solution.